# RHEL8 Limits not applied when setuid is configured

Tags: centos, centos8, limits, rhel8, setuid

I have configured my limits.conf file to allocate a huge stack size

```
*               soft    stack     65535
*               hard    stack     65535
```

`ulimit -s` shows the correct value for both `root` user and `myuser`

With this configuration in place, if I run an executable(owned by `root:root`) from `myuser`, the process is owned by `myuser` and `/proc/<id>/limits` has the right stack size, (as expected)

however, as `root` if I set the `setuid` on the executable and execute it from `myuser`, the process is owned by `root`(as expected), but the stack size in `/proc/<id>/limits` is `8 MB` (I guess this is default size)

In rhel6/rhel7, The stack sizes are allocated as per `limits.conf` with or without `setuid`.

Is this a new behaviour in RHEL8? How can I get the size from limits in this case?